# How to add custom data in wordpress users table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I try to do some thing with wordpress social login plugin. I need to put `steamid` to `wp_users` table. I have to create colum called `steamid` in `wp_users` table.

Trying to do it with:

```
$userdata = array(
    'user_login'    => $user_login,
    'user_email'    => $user_email,

    'display_name'  =>  $user_login,

    'first_name'    => $hybridauth_user_profile->firstName,
    'last_name'     => $hybridauth_user_profile->lastName,
    'user_url'      => $hybridauth_user_profile->profileURL,
    'description'   => $hybridauth_user_profile->description,
    'steamid'   => $user_login,

    'user_pass'     => wp_generate_password()
);
```

But nothing, the table column `steamid` is still empty. What's wrong?

Comment: you don't need to modify the database, you can use that : https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/working-with-user-metadata/

Comment: Not related to your problem but I think it's still worth mentioning: normally you should be saving these additional fields in the `usermeta` table, that's what it's for (to store additional user data without modifying the `user` table.)

Comment: Thanks for reply! I know about usermeta, but i need to save in "wp_users" :)